# How to close a google chrome tab from an android application?

Tags: android, google-chrome, gwt

I am writing an android application to open a tab in chrome when the application is opened. My issue is that, when I close the android application the tab that is opened by the application must be closed in chrome. If my application tab is already opened in Google chrome then that tab must be highlighted else the URL must be loaded in Google chrome.

Comment: How are you opening the tab.  If you launch the page correctly via an Android intent it should appear on the stack of intents and thus you should not be able to kill the applicaiton without also killing the tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can only close windows **opened by a script** trough the js native instruction:

```
$wnd.close
```

You can't close other windows.